# How handle a 5 year old who delays going to the toilet and soils his pants?

Tags: pre-schooler, potty-training, motivation, enuresis, urine

My 5 year old son goes to kindergarten. When it's toilet time he is the show-off.  He was toilet trained but now delays going to the toilet for play or TV watching. He once said monsters are there so I put up a dinosaur picture that he chose since he said dinosaurs scare away monsters but he is still delaying going to the toilet and soils his pants. How to handle it now?

Comment: Not an answer, but an insight:

There is a concept called "flow". It is a repeditive action which is just the right amount of challenging and constantly provides small moments of gratification. It can apply to almost everything from skiing to doing your dishes, but it is particularly strong in good computer games (and can appear by watching television).

It is one of the mayor aspects of flow that humans are more focused on the activity and tend to forget about bodily needs like hunger or the need to visit a toilet. 

Read more about flow, you might find insight and solutions :-)

Answer (score 2):

We were starting to see delay toilet use, so we introduced specific times of the day our son has to try regardless if he feels like it.

- Once in the morning as before going downstairs and starting the day.
- Once before dinner.
- Throughout the day we encourage him to tell us when he as to go.

Some of these times if he does this without complaints we reward via a sticker on a progress chart that can be used as a trip to the book store to buy a book or new dinosaur.

Still early and a work in progress for us.

@Rororo is correct on the flow state. Perhaps mandatory pause and breaks in the action?